# Four letters does a riddle make

Tags: riddle, word

Here's four letters that you can have,

Add another and you'll have a weapon.

With a plural, I'll rise up (you'll see).

Two more and you might have a fallacie (oops).

What am I?

Note: Each of the lines is an expansion of the previous (i.e. in the last line, you should have an eight letter word, not six).

Comment: Is fallacy intentionally misspelled?

Comment: Yes. Hence the 'oops'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> take?

Here's four letters that you can have,

> I'll *take* what you give.

Add another and you'll have a weapon.

> Add an *s* for *stake*, as in the pointy thing for to off vampires and such.

With a plural, I'll rise up (you'll see).

> The plural would be *stakes*, as in *raise the stakes*.

Two more and you might have a fallacie (oops).

> And with two more, we can get *mistakes*, which, though the clue hints at a singular, would be correct if the clue has two errors, including the misspelling.

Comment: Very well done!

Answer (score 2):

My answer assumes I can change the order of all the letters:

Here's four letters that you can have,

> HERE

Add another and you'll have a weapon.

> HEXER "one who applies a hex"

With a plural, I'll rise up (you'll see).

> SHEER "straight up or down without a break"

Two more and you might have a fallacie (oops).

> HERESY

Comment: First line is a clue that's about more than just the four letters, but this was a good attempt.

Also, you don't need to rearrange any of the letters with the word I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer?

Adding 1 letter to get a weapon... I'm gathering a list of 5letter weapons.

> Sword, laser, saber, arrow,spear,rifle

Comment: None of these are the one I'm thinking of, though if you think any one of them might fit the bill, still give it a shot.